# why setInterval method does not work if value function in a var?

Tags: javascript

i need help with js! I used function in a var for type writing effect and entered the var in setInterval method and it did not work but when i entered the same function in `setInterval` it works why???

```js
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var mytext="thequickredfoxjumpsoverthelazybrowndog";
//var i=0;
//var typewriter = null;

// first code function in var 
var x = function() {


  document.getElementById('type')
    .textContent += mytext[i];

  i = i + 1;

  if (i > 20) {

    clearInterval(typewriter);
  }
};


mybutton.onclick = function() {
  'use strict';

  typewriter = setInterval(x, 10);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="mybutton">
<div id="type"></div>
```

```js
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var mytext="thequickredfoxjumpsoverthelazybrowndog";
var i=0;
var typewriter = null;

// second  code function directly in setInterval

mybutton.onclick = function() {
  'user strict';

  var typewriter = setInterval(function() {


    document.getElementById('type')
      .textContent += mytext[i];

    i = i + 1;

    if (i > 20) {

      clearInterval(typewriter);
    }
  }, 10);


};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="mybutton">
<div id="type"></div>
```

Comment: [Off topic]: There's no directive called `"user strict"`... It's `"use strict"`!

Comment: You need to read about scope in Javascript. `typewriter` is `undefined` in `x` because it is locally function-scoped in your anonymous function that you assign to `mybutton.onclick`.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `i` needs to be initialized and needs to be in window scope of the javascript.

Variable `typewriter` needs to be initialized and needs to be in window scope of the javascript. You had it inside a function scope.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('mybutton');
var mytext="thequickredfoxjumpsoverthelazybrowndog";
var i=0;
var typewriter = null;

// first code function in var 
var x = function() {


  document.getElementById('type')
    .textContent += mytext[i];

  i = i + 1;

  if (i > 20) {

    clearInterval(typewriter);
  }
};


mybutton.onclick = function() {
  'use strict';

  typewriter = setInterval(x, 10);
};
```

```html
<input type="button" id="mybutton">
<div id="type"></div>
```